# iOS simulator missing versions?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Just installed xCode 4.1 from the app store today after having reinstalled to Lion (Clean install), but now I have a little problem with the iOS simulator, before Lion i had xCode 4.0 and there I had from 3.2 and up to 4.x.x in my versions menu, so that I could test in different iOS builds, but now I only have 4.3.2, is there any way to get the other back, like for example 4.2.1, 4.1 and so on?

Also is it possible in any way to get 3.1.3 in the simulator as well ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't get it back I'm afraid. Best thing is to use whatever the latest simulator version is available, and in your target's build settings, in the "iOS Deployment Target" setting, pick the oldest iOS version that you want to support. Your application - assuming it compiles - will be compatible on all versions from that one onwards.